# Unable to access properties from an object in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and using VS2013 pro. I have a model called Auction as follows:

```
namespace auctionsite1.Models
{
    public class Auction
    {
        public long id { set; get; }
        public String title { set; get; }
        public String description { set; get; }
        public String imageurl { set; get; }
        public DateTime starttime { get; set; }
        public DateTime endtime { get; set; }
        public decimal startprice { get; set; }
        public decimal currentprice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There is a controller auctions and an action and a  view by name index.
Now I tried to create an object for this class in the view and tried to access the properties but Visual Studio 2013 is unable to find the names in the context of the object:

```
@{
    var a = new auctionsite1.Models.Auction();
    {
        **title** = "hi";    //unable to initialize title as it is not in context.
        **id** = 123;
        **starttime** = DateTime.Now;
    };
}
```

I am unable to understand why it is this way in spite of clearly mentioning the class and its path.

Comment: Remove semicolon after constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shad mentioned, you have a semicolon after the constructor. If you want to use an object initializer, you need to move that to after you've set the properties:

```
@{
    var a = new auctionsite1.Models.Auction()
    {
        title = "hi";
        id = 123;
        starttime = DateTime.Now;
    };
}
```